# How to read the data from a dataframe without using collect method in Spak/Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which contains 2 million records. I want to read each record for my analysis.

But when i use `dataframe.collect()` method which will bring the data from all nodes locally where driver program is running, which would impact achieving parallelism. Is there any solution?

My Configuration is:

```
Cloudera:CDH 5.9.1
Cluster Nodes:5 ->each 8GB RAM
Spark:1.6
Scala:10.5
```

Comment: what do you wanna do with each record ?

Comment: I need to filter the data for each unique id and do analysis of X days of data for each id.

Comment: You need to be more clear. There are lots of function available and you can use UDF and UDAF as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to read that data out, you must perform some kind of action: `collect` is the usual choice when you need the driver program to have access to it. However, if you need to store it somewhere else, you may take advantage of parallel writers available for HDFS, JDBC and so on.

If you need to access that data to compute further results, you can keep the data where it is and just apply functions on it using the usual combinators (`map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and the like).

But if you need to save the results locally, you have no other choice but collecting. It will affect the parallelism of the computation at that point of course, but you are bound to the output you want to have: local storage, local action; distributed storage, distributed action.

Answer (score 0):

`.collect()` is an action, which, as you said will back the results to your driver as a local collection of `Row`. This may be a bottleneck if the size of resultant dataset is huge with respect to your system configuration.

That said, your question is lacking in the sense that you haven't mentioned what you want to do with this data that you've read. If it is just about read the data as a dataframe you can do something like in Spark 1.x.x

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)  

import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sqlContext.read.csv("file:///path/to/input/")
```

use `df` to refer to your dataframe.

You need to do something with this dataframe. For example instead of `collect()` you can save this as a csv on some path like below,

```
df.write.csv("file:///path/to/output")
```

This will work without this driver overhead you were facing earlier.
Let me know if this helped.